# Automatically offset parasite axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating plots with up to 5 parasite y-axes using Matplotlib 3.1 and parasite_axes and I would like to automatically spaces the yaxes instead of specifying an offset in the code. Currently I have to plot the figure to see if the axis overlap then manually adjust the width of the figure to make the correct amount of space for the parasite axes and then manually add an offset to each axis so they don't overlap. If anything changes in the figure, such as DPI or the number of digits in the label, then I have to go through all of this again.

I have tried to get the bbox of just the yaxis but I seem to be unable to get anything except for the bbox of the entire plot. Without knowing the width of the axis there doesn't seem to be any way to calculate the correct spacing for these.

```
#Example from the matplotlib website:
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

offset = 60
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                axes=par2,
                                offset=(offset, 0))

par1.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)
par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.legend()

host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

plt.show()
```